# Controlling the order of evaluation with local variables inside an Integration

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation

I'm trying to evaluate an integral (numerically would be good enough), but since the integrand contains the same expression several times, I'd like to speed it up by defining a local variable that locally evaluates that expression. 
Specifically, I write the following

```
F[σ_] := Integrate[
   Module[{a1x = x, a2x = x^σ},
      If[.2 a1x >= a2x, a1x, a2x]
   ], 
   {x, 0, 1}
]
```

```
F[2]
```

This returns the result

```
(0.2 + 0.8 x) x
```

When really, it should be

```
0.350667
```

(After all, F is simply integrating $x$ over $[0,.2]$ and $x^2$ over $(.2,1]$.

Why is that? And how can it be fixed?

**Edit:** In this specific case, NIntegrate gives me the desired result, albeit with a bunch of warnings. In my actual example however, it just runs without end... and then outputs the result with local variables of the type

```
a1x$12776
```

So I need to be able to somehow force Mathematica to evaluate the a1x expression FIRST each time it tries to figure out an integrand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Piecewise` to define a function that is used as the argument to the integral.

```
p[x_, σ_] := Piecewise[
  {
   {x, x <= 0.2},
   {x^σ, x > 0.2}
   }
  ]
```

Now we will use the funciton `p` as the function to be integrated

```
fp[σ_] := Integrate[p[x, σ], {x, 0, 1}]

fp[2]
(* 0.350667 *)
```